# Train Test leakage

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference, group-differences, differences, train-test-split

Imagine the following dataset. 
1 --> Person buys this product sometimes  
0 --> Person never buys this product:

```
          Noodles  Rice  Pickles ... Chewinggum  Money spent
Person 1        1     0        1              1         1000
Person 2        0     0        0              1          150
Person 3        1     1        1              1          750
...
Person n        1     0        1              0          895
```

Sure this is a dummy dataset. In my real dataset I have too little amount of data. Only about to 70-150 Persons with 2000 features. Therefore "normal" regression approaches to predict "Money spent" directly did not work out so well.

My new approach is to predict the differences in "Money spent"! I take the difference of Person 1 and Person 2, the difference of Person 1 and Person 3 and do this throughout the entire set.

I end up with a dataset of $n^2-n$ rows. First row would look like this:

```
Person 1 Person 2  1    0   1   0   950
Person 1 Person 3  0   -1   0   0   250
```

I now want to create a model to predict how much more money or how much less money Person X spends than Person Y.

I want to create a 75% train 25% test split. The **question** now is:

- A) Do I split the dataset to train and test before computing the differences? This would lead to a training set of $(0.75n)^2 - 0.75n$
- B) Or do I compute the differences and create train test split afterwards? This would result in a trainingset of $(n^2 - n) * 0.75$

My Problem: When Person 23 maybe eats a rare feature "Peanuts" and is the only one with value 1 for "Peanuts". With approach A) the model has no clue what to do with a difference for value "Peanuts" because all other don't differ here. With approach B) I sense that somehow too much information of Person 23 is still in the dataset and leaks to the test results.

I hope you understand what I am talking about. I would like to read your comments on that. Maybe you can provide me some additional information about modeling of differences in general if this is a common approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you compute the differences before splitting the data, as described in option B, you risk introducing data leakage into your test set. Data leakage occurs when information from the test set is used to inform the model during training, leading to overly optimistic performance metrics. In this case, if a rare feature like "Peanuts" is only present in a few individuals, it may disproportionately influence the training data and result in overfitting.

Hence, option A will be a better choice. Additionally, if possible, I suggest that you exclude the features with few observations.